# Spring MockMvc - getting java.time.Instant from REST

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc

I have a resource that returns me an object with `java.time.Instant` property.

```
class X {
    ...
    private Instant startDate;
    ...
}
```

And I am testing it with:

```
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/x"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content.[*].startDate").value(hasItem(MY_INSTANT_DATE)));
```

But what I get from JUnit is:

```
Expected: a collection containing <2018-06-08T11:46:50.292Z> but: was <1528458378.397000000>
```

How can I map my `Instant` date to this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution by making a custom Matcher:

```
class DateEquals extends BaseMatcher<Integer> {

    private final Date expectedValue;

    DateEquals(Date equalArg) {
        expectedValue = equalArg;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        Long dateTimeMillis = (Long) item;
        return dateTimeMillis.equals(toEpochMillis(expectedValue));
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendValue(" equals to date: " + expectedValue);
    }
}
```

Factory for it:

```
public class CustomMatchersFactory {
    public static Matcher dateEquals(Date date) {
        return is(new DateEquals(date));
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.content.[*].startDate", dateEquals(MY_INSTANT_DATE)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is no need for explicit mapping. It happens if Jackson Mapper is told to write dates as timestamps.
So, there are two places to check (because by default this feature is disabled):

- Code
- Application properties

Regarding the code, you can check this Baeldung article where possible ways od ObjectMapper adjustments are shown: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper#customizing-the-default-objectmapper

Regarding the application properties. The appropriate property is `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps`, so either check if it's disabled, or you can explicitly disable it just for your confidence (to remove this point from the list of potential causes):

For *.yaml you can disable it in next way:

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

Or in case if you use `*.properties` file

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```